# For in loop inside or outside UIView.animate block?

Tags: ios, uiviewanimation

Does one of the following functions has an advanced over the other, or does it not matter in performance/best practice?

```
1.
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1){
    for b in self.someArray{
        b.frame.origin = self.myNewPosition
    }
}
```

---

```
2.
for b in self.someArray{
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1){
        b.frame.origin = self.myNewPosition
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try both? What happened?

Comment: @rmaddy I did not noticed any side effects in the functions, however I saw in my code that I am not working consistent on this part and I was wondering if there is a recommended way on animating an array.

Comment: @rmaddy is correct, your choice is option **1.** *loop inside the animation block whenever animations are same.* do accept the answer if it helped :) thanks

Comment: @AamirR I totally forgot about this question, thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Option 1 creates a single animation and all of the updated properties are animated together.

Option 2 creates X number of animations and each one can do whatever you want.

Use option 1 if you want all of the origins to change at the same time for the same duration.

Use option 2 if you want a different animation for each object in the array.